# Change image source with value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<html>
<script type="javascript">
    var building=new Array(10)
    building[1]="images_buildings/abudhabi.jpg"
    building[2]="images_buildings/auckland.jpg"
    building[3]="images_buildings/coffsharbour.jpg"
    building[4]="images_buildings/endinburge.jpg"
    building[5]="images_building/la.jpg"
    building[6]="images_building/london.jpg"
    building[7]="images_building/newyork.jpg"
    building[8]="images_buildings/singapore.jpg"
    building[9]="images_buildings/sydney.jpg"
    building[10]="images_buildings/toronto.jpg"
    var num = 0

    function changepic()
    {
       num=num+1
       if (num==11)
       {num=1}

       document.buildingpic.src=eval("building"+num+".src" )
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
       <img src="images_buildings/abudhabi.jpg" name="buildingpic" width="400"          
height="400" />
       <p><A HREF="JavaScript:changepic()">next</A></p>
    </center>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to research but just couldnt find anything that helped me- once i resolve this i will be adding another pic array and a information array :/ but i was constructing it one at a time
:)

Comment: `</p>` after `</center> has no open `<p>`

Comment: What's the problem?
And you should pick a better title next time.

Comment: [java is not javascript](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=java+vs+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk&redir_esc=&ei=xQudUNP0D-G90QXH1oFQ)

Comment: In the original question's code [http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13309330/1] there's some invalid html that got corrected in later edits.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, try this instead.

```
   document.buildingpic.src=building[num]
```

Answer (score 1):

using this you can add more images to the array without the need to change the workings of the function.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var building = [];
    building[0] = "images_buildings/abudhabi.jpg";
    building[1] = "images_buildings/auckland.jpg";
    building[2] = "images_buildings/coffsharbour.jpg";
    building[3] = "images_buildings/endinburge.jpg";
    building[4] = "images_building/la.jpg";
    building[5] = "images_building/london.jpg";
    building[6] = "images_building/newyork.jpg";
    building[7] = "images_buildings/singapore.jpg";
    building[8] = "images_buildings/sydney.jpg";
    building[9] = "images_buildings/toronto.jpg";
    var num = 0;

   function changepic()
   {

      if (num>=building.length-1){
         num=0;
      }
      num=num+1;
      document.buildingpic.src=building[num];
   }

  </script>
  </head>

 <body>
 <center>
   <img src="images_buildings/abudhabi.jpg" name="buildingpic" width="400" height="400" />
   <p><A href="javascript:changepic();">next</A></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help :) I need to add another array of pictures this time of people , then a text array..... I'm going to try to add myself but if I have probs would you mind looking at it for me as you can see i'm really new to programming :/